# ng-admin date picker filter is initialized with null/NaN values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, ng-admin

I am configuring an admin panel with `ng-admin` + `AngularJs`, I tried to set a date filter:

```
nga.field('created-at', 'date')
        .label('Created At')
        .format('yyyy-MM-dd')
        .defaultValue('2016-10-21')
```

The problem arises when I click on the date picker. The weeks’ numbers on the left are replaced with NaN (Not A Number) and the days names in the top are replaced with null.

Answer (score 0):

After deep search, I discovered some issues related to older versions of ng-admin like:

https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/issues/860
https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/issues/411
https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/issues/854

The solution was simply upgrading the ng-admin package to the latest version.